# VSCode: I want to remove annoying info message bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: VSCode message bar]

Is there any way to **completely remove** this message popup or **move** it to somewhere?

**I already know why this message comes, but I do not want to disturb my activity with annoying info popup.**

When it pops up it hides the document tab, so I have to close it every single time. (I do not want to know how to fix this particular error message, this screenshot is just an example.)

It's very annoying and I've searched around for a way to remove it, but the answers keep saying how to fix that particular error and not how to hide the popup itself.

Comment: I second this. It is really annoying sometimes. Errors appear in the Problems tab when needed. The additional popup gets in the way. Sometimes I have to close many of them just to see the top of my editor again. A single popup that indicates that there are errors and provides a link to show the Problems tab would be more useful.

Comment: Much as pressing escape is the best way to deal with it, it seems an incredible oversight that this can't be turned off, or at least moved somewhere less intrusive (such as to the bottom of the screen.) Its behaviour is incredibly frustrating as it stands.

Answer (score 15):

**Press ESC.**

I agree that this is really annoying. VS Code is all about high-speed workflow and not having to interact with anything except your code via keyboard. Everything has key chords, e.g. CTRL-P and CTRL-SHIFT-P. So having to stop what I'm doing, go to the mouse, and dismiss this popup, whenever a background task feels like completing (and not even really then, because the popup actually appears some short time later) just so I can get visual confirmation of which file I'm currently coding in, to refocus my work after being distracted by the same popup, is really awkward. They are in a stupid location and don't even fade away after time like well-behaved toasts.

That said, I think that's really two parts; the distraction, and relatively high workflow cost to dismiss.

It helped me a lot to learn that **it can be dismissed quickly and easily with the ESC key**. The other half the problem I still haven't solved, but hope that helps you.

Comment: +1, it's annoying that this can't be turned off entirely (or at least displayed in a less annoying way) - but this shortcut has definitely helped my workflow since I've found your answer.

Comment: `ESC` only works if the popup has focus, which it doesn't seem to most of the time. I don't know if this is an implementation detail of whatever plug-in is initiating it.

Comment: No need to be sorry :) Must be something I'm doing wrong or maybe plug-in dependent?

Answer (score 8):

In the screenshot it shows trying to validate PHP.

In a VS Code window select **File** > **Preferences** > **User Settings**

An editor will open on the left called *Default Settings* and on the right with a file called *settings.json*

In the right side editor you can add settings that will override those found in the left-hand-side one.

Between the braces type:

```
// Whether php validation is enabled or not.
    "php.validate.enable": false,
```

Then save the document.

VS Code will no longer attempt to validate PHP files.

You can override any of the defaults using this method.

You can use the same technique for each Workspace (or project folder) using **File** > **Preferences** > **Workspace Settings**

You can't disable the alert bar in general as VS Code needs to tell you things and doesn't (thankfully) use modal dialogs to communicate.

Answer (score 4):

Go to File > preferences > settings

Then add this to your user settings

"editor.parameterHints": false

Comment: Thank god. This got rid of the annoying toaster.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try adding the line

`"extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true`

to your VS Code settings file (which you can easily reach with the keystroke (CMD + ,) on a Mac OS X or macOS system.)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: **User Preferences** > change `"editor.parameterHints": true` to `"editor.parameterHints": false`

This will at least remove the obstructive boxes that appear above the cursor.

Comment: This is a duplicate response of Jry